# How do I configure the item decay time (of a death corpse bag) in my ARK server?

Tags: server-administration, ark-survival-evolved

I have set the `GlobalItemDecompositionTimeMultiplier` field with a value of **1.0** inside the `[/Script/ShooterGame.ShooterGameMode]` section of the **Game.ini** file.

A multiplier of 1.0 I read that in theory is equivalent as 15 minutes for the decomposition of a death corpse bag (the bag that your corpse drops when you die), however, when I run my server with this configuration, it shows three hours for decomposition...

[image]

I want to set a normal item decay time, what I'm missing?, what value I must change in the .ini files of the server to specify the desired time interval I want for item decomposition?.

Comment: What are your `GlobalSpoilingTimeMultiplier` and `GlobalCorpseDecompositionTimeMultiplier` set to? Do you have any mods installed?